# Pausing an enhanced for loop

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask

I am using an enhanced for loop and a switch statement to trigger various AsyncTasks. How can I pause each iteration of the loop to wait until any given AsyncTask is compeleted? I was trying to spawn a thread and wait / join / notify when each AsyncTask is complete but I just keep freezing up the UI. Below is my code snippet...

```
for (Integer integer : sequence) {

    switch (integer) {
        case 1: // Async process
            break;
        case 2: // Async process
            break;
        case 3: // Async process
            break;
        case 4: // Async process
            break;
        default: break;


        }

        //Need magic solution here...

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is not a good choice. Add a 'finish' callback after each AsyncTask(). Create this kind of chain of code. You can save the last added in the chain so you can add new item in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the AsyncTask, use `.get()` like so:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute().get();
```

This will pause your code until the AsyncTask returns something

Edit: Another option is to throw the for loop in its own AsyncTask so that it is also backgrounding, allowing you to interact with the UI

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you're doing is not a good design choice. You should never block the UI Thread or you will face the infamous ANR error message.

If you want to use the `AsyncTask` class, then try to use it the way it is supposed to be used. An `AsyncTask` is used, as the name says, for asynchronous background operations (and short ones!), but you're synchronizing the main thread with its execution, nullyfying its entire purpose.

Do your background work in `doInBackground()` and then notify the UI thread in `onPostExecute()`. This method is guaranteed to be executed on the UI Thread so you don't have to worry about concurrency issues. You can also use `onPorgressUpdate()` and `onPreExecute()` to notify the UI Thread from the `AsyncTask`.

For more specific suggestions, you should give us more hints about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to use the AsyncTask for a Simon-says like process. The loop is to iterate through each button (based on an Integer value). I'm using the AsyncTask to sleep for 1 second in the doInBackground method, while using both onPreExecute and onPostExecute to update the button states on the UI. Is there a better way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Move all the control code in its own thread and update the UI asnchronously. AsyncTask is not the best way to handle long running background operations. Try to use your own thread and communicate with the UI Thread through an Handler. Keep the UI Thread as clean as possible and only perform UI related operations on it.